# EAR with WARs containing different versions of dependencies

Tags: java, maven, war, pom.xml, ear

Here is my requirement

EAR 
WAR (Code) 
----Dependency A v1 
WAR (Code same as WAR above) 
----Dependency A v2 

AS the code for WAR project is same I don't want to create multiple code base for WAR project. So I'm looking for EAR pom.xml in such a way that maven builds the WAR with dependency A v1 which can be passed as some property while building WAR.


EAR pom.xml 
... 
(modules) 
  (webmodule) 
    (artifact)WAR(/artifact) 
    dependency version v1 
    (content-path)/warwithv1(/content-path) 
  (/webmodule) 
  (webmodule) 
    (artifact)WAR(/artifact) 
    dependency version v2 
    (content-path)/warwithv2(/content-path) 
  (/webmodule) 
... 


Thanks

Sorry for the XML Tags

Comment: How about using [profiles](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Profiles) to specify different dependencies and then activate the appropriate profile during the WAR build?

Comment: The question is what you mean by `..  don't want to create multiple code base for WAR..`? If you have code which used by both create a separate module which contains that code...so in the end you have only the WAR project which contains different dependencies (if you really need that)..What kind of dependencies are different ?

Comment: @khmarbaise I mean I don't want to replicate the WAR Code in git repository because its going to be same just the dependency will be of different versions

Comment: @D.B. Can you elaborate more, pardon my ignorance, as I new to maven

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**: Answer changed after clarification in comments.

The question as I now understand it is: How does one use a single POM to create 2 WAR files that both have the same source code but different dependencies.

The solution I propose is to create a parent POM that will specify one module per WAR. One of the modules will contain the source code for the war and specify one version of dependencies. The second module will refer to the first module for its source code and will specify a second version of dependencies.

Here is my high level project structure:

[image]

Here is the top level (parent) POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>maven-war-diff-depend</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-diff-depend</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>module1</module>
        <module>module2</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

Module1 will specify v2.3 of log4j2, here is its POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>maven-war-diff-depend</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-diff-depend</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>module1</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Module2 will specify v2.8.1 of log4j2 and point to module1 for its source code and web.xml file. Note that you may need to do additional work to refer to any other resources in module1 such as adding more maven plugins and configuration.

Here is the module2 POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>maven-war-diff-depend</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-diff-depend</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>module2</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>../module1/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                <webXml>../module1/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Note that I only have a single Java class in module1 just to show that in fact this class is compiled and included in both module1 and module2:

[image]

Here are the results of a simple clean install build:

[image]

[image]

Once you have the two WAR files built it's fairly simple to add another module (this would be your EAR) which will include both of the WAR files - I believe that is your final goal.

So, create a third module:

[image]

Add the new module to your root level (parent) POM:

`<module>module3</module>`

Create the necessary configuration in your new module's POM. This involves adding dependencies on the other two artifacts you create with module1 and module2 and configuring the ear plugin as needed.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>maven-war-diff-depend</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-diff-depend</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>module3</artifactId>
    <packaging>ear</packaging>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
                <configuration>
                    <applicationXml>${basedir}/target/application.xml</applicationXml>
                    <modules>
                        <webModule>
                            <groupId>maven-war-diff-depend</groupId>
                            <artifactId>module1</artifactId>
                        </webModule>
                        <webModule>
                            <groupId>maven-war-diff-depend</groupId>
                            <artifactId>module2</artifactId>
                        </webModule>
                    </modules>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>maven-war-diff-depend</groupId>
            <artifactId>module1</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>maven-war-diff-depend</groupId>
            <artifactId>module2</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Now when you build it will create an EAR that includes the 2 WARs generated by module1 and module2. The ear in this example is simply called module3:

[image]

[image]

**EDIT: Original answer re-added per request in comments.**

Here is the POM from the original proposal - using two profiles to specify different dependency versions. As before please note that it's not a good idea to include servlet api inside of a WAR file, it's just being used here as a visual example to show how common dependencies are specified.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>maven-war-diff-depend</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-diff-depend</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>v2.3</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>v2.8.1</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation, building WAR 2 times with different profile. But How can we achieve this with Single pom.xml for EAR ?? I'm still looking for a solution to get this done inside EAR.

Comment: @Ritz009 Answer edited to demonstrate one way to create two WARs with different dependencies using a build triggered against a single POM file.

Comment: How to include Parent POM from your answer into EAR pom.xml. Can you modify the the Parent POM as EAR pom.xml ?

Comment: No, you would not want the EAR pom to be the parent you would want a 3rd module that is built after the 2 WARs are built. I will add this to the answer

Comment: In your proposed solution, we've to maintain 2 web-projects (1 with just pom.xml pointing to common source), meaning if there are 3 different version of dependencies then 3 need to be created. What I was looking for was to configure EAR or PARENT pom.xml in such a way that it creates all the number of WARs (with diff dep versions) and embeds into EAR. Another issue with this approach is about the common dependencies. Because all the WARs will have to lot of common dependencies, and would have to be declared again.

Comment: Each POM is intended to create exactly one artifact, to violate that would not be good practice and I'm not even sure it's possible. That's why I suggested this approach. With regard to duplication you can always add another module to capture the common dependencies and other configuration and then declare the parent of that module to be the root level POM. Then the WAR modules would declare their parent as this new module, not the root pom as shown above.

Comment: For Common Dependencies I got that part for creating a WAR-Common Parent. I'm not able to see the profile based solution that you proposed earlier ?

Comment: I can put that back in. I just didn't want to clutter the answer with irrelevant info since it seemed like that wasn't the direction you wanted to go.