# Maven build 2 versions of war with different versions of dependencies

Tags: java, maven, war

I have a maven war project which needs to be build with different versions of a dependency due to target environments.

Currently I am doing it with maven profiles(having different versions of dependency as property).

Below are the issues currently having:

1. I need to run build with different profiles twice
2. Not sure how change war version for maven repo deploy

   for ex: 1.0.0-parallel, 1.0.0-prod where pom.xml has 1.0.0

I saw below solution but it needs to create separate modules:
[EAR with WARs containing different versions of dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43268002/ear-with-wars-containing-different-versions-of-dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

Create a multi-module project that contains two WAR modules and an additional `commons` module that contains all the common code.

This allows you to create two very similar WARs in one build.

Comment: Thanks but that will same approach that i mentioned already, drawback will be that new module need to created and managed just for the sake of dependency.

Comment: It will be the easiest and most maintainable way. You can of course run the maven war plugin twice and create a side artifact, but this will be more difficult to handle.